# Is there typographical error in Stephen Willard's General Topology proof of Theorem 28.11

Tags: general-topology, order-theory, connectedness, separation-axioms

Here is 28.11:

[image: image of proof 28.11]

The proof on page 206 initially refers to separation order E(a,b). In the second paragraph, it supposes distinct points in E(a,c) - {a,b}. I am reading this on my own so I have no-one else to ask. I believe it should read E(a,b) - {a,b}. Am I correct?

It turns I believe that there is an error in the following proof as well. Here's 28.12:

[image: image of proof 28.12]

The third line of the proof should read "q > p." The fourth line is correct.

There may be yet a third typo in section 28 in the proof of 28.14. The proof reads "...form a chain of connected sets whose union is K - {x,y}..."

Regardless, I am only asking for an answer to the question regarding theorem 28.11. Any comments regarding the other 2 proofs would be welcome but are not needed.

If I am correct, I hope this will be helpful for those who read General Topology in the future.

Comment: It may be helpful to post the context in which you found it, either by writing it out or by taking a picture if it's too complicated.

Comment: Assuming that you’re talking about the proof of Theorem 23.11, you are correct.

Comment: I am referring to 28.11, not 23.11. As there is no Theorem 23.11, I suspect we are referring to the same typographical error.

Comment: Brian M. Scott, can you please write your own answer to this question rather than commenting on my question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is an error. Brian Scott confirmed this in the comments section.

Comment: You should have added the text to your question. As it is, you did **not** give an answer.

Comment: Paul, You are correct. I am sorry. I am new to StackExchange and was simply trying to provide the actual text of the theorem. At this time, I believe Brian Scott confirmed the error and that the question is answered.

Comment: There is no reason to be sorry. Nobody is perfect ;-) By the way, this forum has the problem that many  questions are answered by **comments**. Unfortunately, this does not make it visible that an answer is available. You should ask the commentator to write an official answer, alternatively you can write an own answer and acknowledge it. But do not write an answer like " I consider Brian Scott's response to have answered my question regarding 28.11 in the affirmative". People do not want to read comments to understand what is going on. Your answer should be self-contained.

Comment: Please explain precisely how you would like me to handle this. Brian Scott answered my question in the comments section of my answer. I have asked him to provide a proper answer but he has not.